# null pointer exception help

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` that I couldnt handle. I'm a newbie in java so I'd appreciate any help.

```
<%
Employee employees[] = (Employee []) request.getAttribute("arr");
Integer arr_size= (Integer) request.getAttribute("arr_size");
for(int i=0;i<employees.length;i++){ %>
<tr><td><b>.</b></td><td><%=employees[i].getName()%></td><td>
    <%=employees[i].getLname()%></td><td><%=employees[i].getType()%></td><td>
    <%=employees[i].getEmail()%></td><td><a href="">Edit Employee Details</a></td>
</tr>
<%}%>
```

`arr` array and `arr_size` is passed from a servlet and I jsp gives an `NullPointerException`.

I tried checking if `employees` and `arr_size` is `null` or not but it doesn't change anything.

thanks.

Comment: Looks like you're never using arr_size so it must be employees or one of the employees elements that is null.  What code did you try to check for the null?

Comment: I tried

if(employees!=null){
for loop
}

and yes full stack trace is int the logs but I dont know how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if the array itself isn't null, it's quite possible that `employees[i]` would be null - leading to a `NullPointerException`. You could avoid this by skipping such elements:

```
for(int i=0;i<employees.length;i++) { 
    if (employees[i] == null) {
        continue;
    }
%>
```

It's not terribly elegant, mind you. I'd also suggest using the enhanced for loop if you're compiling with Java 5, which would make the code cleaner:

```
<%
Employee employees[] = (Employee []) request.getAttribute("arr");
for (Employee employee : employees) {
    if (employee == null) {
        continue;
    } %>
<tr><td><b>.</b></td><td><%=employee.getName()%></td><td>
    <%=employee.getLname()%></td><td><%=employee.getType()%></td><td>
    <%=employee.getEmail()%></td><td><a href="">Edit Employee Details</a></td>
</tr>
<%}%>
```

Note that I've ignored `arr_size` as you didn't appear to be using it. What was it meant to represent?

Finally, I'd suggest moving logic outside your JSP if at all possible...

Comment: What logic?  All he's doing is printing out the contents.  It's not like he's doing calculations on them or something.

Comment: I agree about leaving logic out of the jsp but I need to display an array as you see, is there a way to to that other than this way?

Comment: Kudos on your analysis skills, Jon Skeet! But I'd like to inject that it's not a good idea for darcrc to become dependent on SO like this. "Teach a man to fish" and all that. So he needs to learn where to find the stack trace (which makes finding the bug much, much easier).

Comment: @Paul: I agree that it's not doing a lot of logic, but it's still ugly including all of that plain Java code within the JSP. I prefer to use technologies which don't mix things up quite so much.

Answer (score 0):

They only thing that I can see that you haven't checked yet is the elements of your employees array. If `employees[i]` is `null` at any point, referencing it will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Try this:

```
for(int i=0;i<employees.length;i++){ 
  Employee e = employees[i];
  if (e != null) {%>
    //current code you have goes here
  <% }} %>
```

instead of the current for loop